# Creating Trigger on Insert Command MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger for when someone enters a salary number that is less than a number already present in my database. I know how to make it in Java and C, just not in SQL.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER InsertError
       ON  dbo.Employee_audit
       AFTER Insert
    AS 
    BEGIN
        IF (SELECT Salary FROM dbo.Employee_audit) < 25000
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR('Salary is too low')
                END 
    END
    GO
```

I know this is incorrect, but there seems to be little resources or examples of specific scenarios.

Comment: You can refer to the newly inserted value using the `NEW` table qualifier: e.g. `IF NEW.Salary < 25000 THEN SIGNAL ...`.  However, beware that signalling an error from an `AFTER INSERT` trigger will, as the name implies, only occur *after the data has already been successfully inserted*.  If you intend to prevent the data from being inserted, you should use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger instead.

Comment: So would it look like

       `IF NEW.Salary < 25000
        THEN SIGNAL('Salary is too low;)
END`

? I'm just confused because I have little training for commands and syntax of SQL

Comment: Also, when I just tried to change the `AFTER INSERT` to `BEFORE INSERT`, the `BEFORE` didn't change blue like it does to indicate the `AFTER`.

Comment: Perhaps you should read the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/), especially some of the examples it contains.  The pages on [`CREATE TRIGGER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-trigger.html) and [`SIGNAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/signal.html) are particularly relevant.